# Hiding parts of a web page from non-members using PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to hide the following code listed below from members that are not logged in how can I do this? And what parts of my code do I need to change or add to it?

Here is the code I want only logged in members to see.

```
<div id="r">
    <h2>some thing</h2>
        <form method="post" action="index.php">
            <fieldset>
                <input type="text" size="40" class="g" name="tag" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['tag'])) echo $_POST['tag']; ?>" />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="s" class="t" />
                <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" />
                <br />
                <span>(Some words)</span>
            </fieldset>
        </form> 
</div>
```

Comment: What kind of authentication/session mechanism do you use? I.e. how can your script determine if it is handling a request for a logged-in user?

Comment: `<?php if (!isset($_SESSION['userid'])) ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depends on how you are tracking how they are logged in. I'm assuming you have something in $_SESSION. if you, so you can just do this:

```
<?php if($_SESSION['logged_in']): ?> //whatever variable you use for logins.
    <div id="r">
       //your html here
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Ah. Looks like you beat me to it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you've stored a boolean that indicated whether someone is logged in with something like `$_SESSION['loggedin']`. In this case, all you really need to do is:

```
<?php

if ($_SESSION['loggedin']) {
  echo <<<HTML
<div id="r">
        <h2>some thing</h2>
                <form method="post" action="index.php">
                        <fieldset>
                                <input type="text" size="40" class="g" name="tag" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['tag'])) echo $_POST['tag']; ?>" />
                                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="s" class="t" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" />
                                <br />
                                <span>(Some words)</span>
                        </fieldset>
                </form> 
</div>
HTML;
}

?>
```